# Manually Configure Spring Boot Reactive Mongo

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-reactive

I'm trying to setup, a PoC of Spring Boot application with multiple databases. Which db should be used is determined by a Spring Profile. One of this DB's is MongoDb to which I am connecting using Spring Data Reactive.

Because I want the application to connect to mongo only when a certain profile is active, I've disabled *MongoAutoconfiguration* and *MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration*.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
        MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class,
        MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class DndApplication {}
```

I've set up a DbConfig, which extends *AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration* and is only used when a mongo profile is active and has *EnableReactiveMongoRepositories* annotation

```
@Profile(value = Array("mongo"))
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
class DbConfig @Autowired()(private val mongoProperties: MongoProperties) extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

  override def reactiveMongoClient(): MongoClient = {
    MongoClients.create()
  };

  override def getDatabaseName: String = "dnd-character"
}
```

With only that, the application works fine, the connection to mongo is created only when mongo profile is active. However, when I try to use a *ReactiveCrudRepository*, for example:

```
@Component
@Profile(value = Array("mongo"))
class MongoCharacterDao @Autowired()(private val repository: CharacterCrudRepository) extends CharacterDao {}
```

and

```
@Profile(value = Array("mongo"))
trait CharacterCrudRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository[MongoCharacterEntity, MongoCharacterId]
```

then it cannot find the *CharacterCrudRepository* Bean and fails on startup

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.velocit.dnd.character.persistence.mongo.MongoCharacterDao required a bean of type 'com.velocit.dnd.character.persistence.mongo.CharacterCrudRepository' that could not be found.
```

When I remove the exclusion of autoconfiguration, the repository works fine, but I cannot limit it only to mongo profile (the application tries to connect to mongo even if all of the mongo beans are restricted to a profile).